# Where to find similar channels to a given channel in Telegram?

Tags: telegram

On Instagram (web version), you can use this button, to see a list of suggested pages that are similar to the current page. This makes it easy to find a lot of resources on this network.

[image]

Is there a similar feature in Telegram anywhere? I want to find channels which are similar to the current channel I'm in. But I can't find how.

Answer (score 2):

Telegram doesn't have a similar channels or groups feature but there are Telegram directories where you can search for channels and groups based on keyword and also find matching ones; one such directory is https://tdirectory.me.

Telegram Directory:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

as of today (30 Nov 2023) you can.

you can open channel information, where you can also see shared media, music, gifs, etc. The last tab is called "Similar Channels" where you can find what you mentioned.
I'm not sure about how they're selected but what makes sense to me is a method based on mutual subscribers.

Answer (score 1):

Telegram doesn't recommend you similar channels. However, **public channels** are displayed when you use the **global search** that is available in telegram.

Global search usually matches the username. It doesn't have to be an exact match. Eg: If you search "programming" the results will be **groups and channels** which contains the text "programming". So, you might get "c programming" or "programming group".

Another way of finding similar channels is by associating with groups, as people tend to share stuffs from various groups.